# flask-login cookie: is it a random value or does it carry encrypted information?

Tags: flask, cookies, flask-login

I use flask-login package to authenticate users. The server provides a cookie to the client upon login, which the client includes in its subsequent requests. Is this cookie a random value? or is it encrypted information that the server decrypts?

If it is a random value, then the server needs a database to map users to their cookies. But I could not find any such database.

if it is encrypted information, where could I find some evidence/documentation of that?

My goal is to understand how the server uses the cookie to authenticate requests.